# Is wine downwards compatible?

Tags: wine, compatibility

Is wine downwards compatible?

Didn't find anything on google unfortunately.

For example: Does wine3.x fulfill dependecies for software that require wine 1.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine is upwards compatible with software requiring >= earlier versions of Wine. Wine 3.x fulfills the dependency requirement for software that requires Wine 1.x.

Comment: Another quick question: Where is the difference between wine1.7 and wine1.7-dev?

Comment: wine 1.7 and wine1.7-dev are transitional dummy packages to ease the migration to the newer Debian wine packages (*wine-stable*). They can be safely removed. *wine-stable* provides essential wrappers and convenience tools for the standard Wine components. It also employs the Debian alternatives system to provide the usual command names, e.g. "wine" instead of "wine-stable".

Comment: For the sake of accuracy there is no wine1.7 or wine1.7-dev in the Ubuntu repositories, those packages are called wine1.6 and wine1.6-dev and in 17.10 and later they are both transitional packages.